# Error in retrieving data from PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on `facebook sdk 4.0` for php. i retrieved friend list in array and I'm unable to access picture from the array. array format is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => AaJvu1z_MAA0INV57e4Bg5hOCaJDzObdptiArw
                    [name] => Mr. John
                    [picture] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [data] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [is_silhouette] => 
                                    [url] => https://fbprofile-a.akamaihd.net/picture.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )
)
```

My PHP Code is:

```
foreach ($friend_list['data'] as $friends) {
    $id = $friends->id;
    $name = $friends->name;
    $picture = $friends['data']->picture;
    echo "ID: ".$id."<br>";
    echo "Name: ".$name."<br>";
    echo "Picture: ".$picture."<br>";
}
```

"ID" and "Name" works fine. but there is an error in "picture object":

> Error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: should be $friends['data'][0]->picture->data->url;

Comment: `$friends->picture->data->url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$picture = $friends->picture->data->url;
```

As you use object retrieval ,also your order was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
foreach ($friend_list['data'] as $friends) {
    $id = $friends->id;
    $name = $friends->name;
    $picture = $friends->picture->data->url;
    echo "ID: ".$id."<br>";
    echo "Name: ".$name."<br>";
    echo "Picture: ".$picture."<br>";
}
```